# chart.js TypeError: item is null

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm writing an application which pulls data from a server into a wrapper component, formats the data, and passes it to multiple chart components. However, when I go to create the chart object, I get the error: `TypeError: item is null`.

Here's my code:

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<h1>A</h1>
<app-chart *ngIf="dataLoaded | async" [type]="'charta'" [data]="{labels: this.data.labels, readings: this.data.charta}"></app-chart>
<h1>B</h1>
<app-chart *ngIf="dataLoaded | async" [type]="'chartb'" [data]="{labels: this.data.labels, readings: this.data.chartb}"></app-chart>
```

**chart.component.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
<canvas [attr.id]="type" width="400" height="400" >{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

**chart.component.ts**

```
....
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() type: string;

  chart: any;

  createChart() {
    const canvas = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#${this.type}`);
    this.chart = new Chart(canvas, {....});
  }

  ....

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.createChart();
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late, but still, what worked for me in a similar issue was the order of things.

Following the example on `Chart.js` I have placed the charting portion in a `test.js`, which I called at the start of the `body` tag. That was followed by the `canvas`. The error was due to the fact that the `canvas` needs to appear before the `js` call.

For example, ***index.php***:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Charting</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>

        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then ***test.js***:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: wow..you are right..the order of things, I was using vuejs and I had to initialize on mounted instead of created..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using ViewChild instead

Try this

**chart.component.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
<canvas #myChart width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
</div>
```

**chart.component.ts**

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() type: string;

  chart: any;

  @ViewChild('myChart')
  myChart: ElementRef;

  createChart() {
    const canvas = this.myChart.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
    this.chart = new Chart(canvas, {....});
  }

  ....

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.createChart();
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up fixing it by passing `this.type` as a string to `new Chart()` and then calling the function in `ngAfterViewInit()`